# sql server 2005 constraints and validations

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table that stores payment details with columns: (`paymentmethod`- which is in either check, cash or creditcard), (`Checknumber`), (`Cardholdersname`), (`creditcardnumber`).

Question is: how do I validate that when `paymentmethod` is `cash` or check then `Cardholdersname`, `creditcardnumber` should be left blank and when `paymentmethod` is `creditcard` then `Checknumber` should be left blank.

Answer (score 1):

You really have two different tables:

```
PaymentDetails(ID, PaymentMethod) and
CreditCardDetails (PaymentDetailsID, CardholderName, CreditCardNumber)
```

All columns are non-nullable in both tables.

---

It is possible to keep all three cases in the same table. In that case, try the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PaymentDetails]
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    PaymentMethod INT NOT NULL CHECK (PaymentMethod IN (1,2,3)), -- Cash, Check, Credit
    CheckNumber int NULL,
    CardHoldersName nvarchar(100) NULL,
    CreditCardNumber varchar(20) NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PaymentDetails]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PaymentTypeConstraint] 
    CHECK  ((PaymentMethod = 1 AND CheckNumber IS NULL AND 
                                   CardholdersName IS NULL AND
                                   CreditCardNumber IS NULL) OR
            (PaymentMethod = 2 AND CheckNumber IS NOT NULL AND 
                                   CardholdersName IS NULL AND
                                   CreditCardNumber IS NULL) OR
            (PaymentMethod = 3 AND CheckNumber IS NULL AND 
                                   CardholdersName IS NOT NULL AND
                                   CreditCardNumber IS NOT NULL));
```

Comment: thanx but i would like to keep all columns in one table

Comment: got this eror: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'CardholderName'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'CreditCardNumber'.